# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'Name''

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Trying to solve this mistery!
I have this dynamics structure that works only in some cases:

This is where I mount the dynamic object

```
string President { get; set; } = "Boss";
string Name { get; set; } = "USA";
int Population { get; set; } = 600000;
Region[] Regions { get; set; }
        
internal dynamic CreateRegion(dynamic req)
{
    Regions = new Region[] { new("NY"), new("MI") };
    return new
    {
        Name,
        Population,
        Regions,
        President
    };
}
```

This is where I consume my dynamic  type:

```
var response = italy.CreateRegion(req);

Console.WriteLine(response);
Console.WriteLine(response.Name);
Console.WriteLine(response.Population);
Console.WriteLine(response.President);

foreach (var region in response.Regions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(region.Name.ToString());
}
```

The field Name is present in the object and I can see this. But When  I try to call it, it returns the error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does
> not contain a definition for 'Name''

[image]
[image]

Comment: i would avoid using `dynamic`. use classes

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code you misspell "President" field to "Presindent"

```
return new
    {
        Name = this.Name,
        Population = this.Population,
        Regions = Regions,
        Presindent = this.President,
    };
```

I think you have same situation with "Name", maybe you used another "a" character or something else. Main point, that it's spelling error, so try to change it. Also if you want to use dynamic further, you can just write like this:

```
 return new
        {
            Name,
            Population,
            Regions,
            President,
        };
```

But I would recommend to use classes. By the functionality, that you have, I would assume, that you want to create region for Country. You can do this just by creating Region separate from Country class, for example like this:

```
class Region{
    public static Region Create(... fields) => new (){...fields}
}
```

And just add it directly to your Country entity:

```
var region = Region.Create(data);
italy.Regions.Add(region);
```

Comment: No. Unfortunately, it didn't work. It's not about misspellings.  I corrected and it still complains.  I updated my code.  I also don't understand why it prints out all the properties correctly on the console.   Furthermore, If I remove "Regions" from the struct , it works!

Comment: @helloB, very strange, my friend, i copied all of your code and it's working fine on my setup, i event downloaded .net5, because i thought, that issue could be related to .net version, but, unfortunately, it's not, so i have no versions beside misspelling :DDD